# Array destructuring - unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript

```
const [a, b] = [1, 2]
// expected to be equal to 
// const a = 1
// const b = 2
const [c, d] = [3, 4]
// expected to be equal to 
// const c = 3
// const d = 4
[a, b] = [b, a] 
// expected Assignment to constant variable error
console.log(a, b, c, d)
// => 1, 2, 2, 1
```

Can someone explain what is wrong with this code? What happened to variables c and d?

Comment: err, assigning new value to `const`?

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using semi-colons and ASI doesn't always work the way you would like.

Your code is equivalent to this:

```js
const [a, b] = [1, 2];

const [c, d] = [3, 4][a, b] = [b, a];

console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

`[3, 4][a, b]` in this case evaluates as `[3,4][2]` since the second comma is just the comma operator and `b === 2`. That makes the assignment equivalent to `[3,4][2] = [b,a]` which results in a temporary array `[3,4,[2,1]]` being created and the result of the assignment expression `[2,1]` is then assigned to `[c,d]`.

Try adding semi-colons and you will get the expected results:

```js
const [a, b] = [1, 2];
// expected to be equal to 
// const a = 1
// const b = 2
const [c, d] = [3, 4];
// expected to be equal to 
// const c = 3
// const d = 4
[a, b] = [b, a];
// expected Assignment to constant variable error
console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

Comment: `const` should be either `var` or `let` in order for this to compile.

Comment: Great answer:))

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a problem with not terminating commands properly with a semi-colon (`;`). If you add them to the end of each command you will get the proper result.. and also run into the problem where you cannot reassign `a` and `b` as they're declared as `const`.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of:

```
const [a, b] = [1, 2];
```

Try:

```
const a = 1, b = 2;
const c = 3, d = 4;
```

To swap the values, try something like:

```
var temp;
temp = a; a = b; b = temp;
```

Comment: What OP does is correct logically, but incorrect syntactically. What you've suggested is correct, but not desirable in the context of this question.